# If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ is a prime then there exists an element of order $8$ mod $p$

Tags: number-theory

I’m trying to show that if $p \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ is a prime then $x^4 \equiv -1 \bmod p$ has a solution. I already knew that if there is an element of order $8$ mod $p$ then the previous congruence equation has a solution but I do not know how to show the existence of such an element.

Comment: $p$ has a primitive root.

Comment: @B. Goddard can you elaborate more on that please ?

Comment: If $r$ is a primitive root, then what is the order of $r^{(p-1)/8}$?

Comment: I see it now, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an ad-hoc solution. Since $p\equiv 1\,(\mathrm{mod}\,8)$, both $-1$ and $2$ are quadratic residue modulo $p$, i.e. there exists $a, b$ such that $a^{2} \equiv -1$ and $b^{2} \equiv 2$ mod $p$. Then the statement is equivalent to show that $a$ is again a square, i.e. $c^{2} \equiv a\,(\mathrm{mod}\,p)$ for some $c$. In fact, it is possible to *construct* $c$ from $a$ and $b$: $c = 2^{-1}b + ab^{-1}$ actually gives $c^{2} \equiv a$ (where $2^{-1}$ is an inverse of $2$ modulo $p$).

Comment: +1. How did you derive the construction of $c$?

Comment: @user2661923 Although I don't have any clear explanation for the derivation, there's a proof of $\left(\frac{2}{p}\right) = 1$ iff $p\equiv \pm 1\,(\mathrm{mod}\,8)$ in Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic*, which uses primitive 8-th root of unity $\zeta_{8}$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ to get $y = \zeta_{8} + \zeta_{8}^{-1}$ that gives $y^{2} = 2\,(\mathrm{mod}\,p)$. I tried similar approach and first I try to find $t$ such that $(b + tb^{-1})^{2} \equiv a$, and I realized that finding $t$ with $(b + tb^{-1})^{2} \equiv 4a$ is actually easier.